# submit button in the new view is processed by index action instead of create action

Tags: submit

I don't know what is wrong! but when i click on the create button in the new view it fires post but uses controller#index action to process it. 
Do you have any idea what the problem is, or how can i specify what action to be used.

it's working fine with the update action, the only problem is in the new form.

Thanks

For future viewers:the problem is solved
root :to => 'class#index'#, :as => 'class' was the issue, removing :as => 'class' solved it

Comment: What button are you referring to?

Comment: @Jay: Thank you!I used scaffold to create this class, i'm refereeing to the default button that is created in the new.html.erb. To be clear, after scaffold in the index.html.erb there is a newCLASS link, clicking on that takes me to the new.html.erb which shows the form, after filling the form, the user will click on the create button, this is the button that i'm talking about.

Comment: @Jay: thank you.solved it. will edit the Q with the solution